# Javascript unable to append options in "select"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, append

In the below function I am trying to add options in the drop down list that I have on my html page.

```
function getProcessors(){
var ctrl = document.getElementById("AgentlList");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Kiwi";
alert(option.text);
ctrl.append(option.text);
//1. ctrl.append("abc");
//2. ctrl.append("<option value='Auditor1'>abc</option>");
//3. ctrl.add("abc");
}
```

as you can see in the above code besides the line "ctrl.append(option.text);" I have tried other 3 ways as well (commented out) but none of them works.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong and how can I add options in the combobox of my html page.

Regards,
Premanshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing native javascript with jQuery.
You have a native DOM node, and to append it, you'd use `appendChild`.
To set it's text, you'd use `textContent`, not `text`.

```
function getProcessors(){
    var ctrl   = document.getElementById("AgentlList");
    var option = document.createElement("option");

    option.textContent = "Kiwi";

    ctrl.appendChild(option);
}
```

Had you been using jQuery, you could do

```
function getProcessors(){
    var ctrl   = $("#AgentlList");
    var option = $("<option />");

    option.text("Kiwi");

    ctrl.append(option);
}
```

Comment: Thank you adeneo for your response however when I tried the first option you gave I got the below error in the console

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference

Comment: the second option also does not works and I get error saying getProcessors is undefiened

Comment: The first one fails because there's no element with the ID `AgentlList`, the second seems to fail because it's not in the scope you're calling it.

Comment: Hi adeneo... you are correct the irst one failed because of a typo in the ID "AgentList" I have made the correction and it works fine now. Thank you so much for your help :) Cheers.